# How to read claims from SamlSecurityToken

Tags: c#, saml, wif, claims-based-identity, adfs

I authenticate on ADFS from code and get a decrypted `SamlSecurityToken`:

```
var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
    new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential),
    "https://my-adfs-domain.com/adfs/services/trust/13/UserNameMixed")
{
    TrustVersion = System.ServiceModel.Security.TrustVersion.WSTrust13,
    Credentials =
    {
        UserName =
        {
            UserName = "username",
            Password = "password"
        }
    }
};

var token = (GenericXmlSecurityToken)factory.CreateChannel().Issue(
    new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("https://my-service-domain.com"),
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
        RequestDisplayToken = true
    });

SamlSecurityToken decryptedToken;

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
        token.TokenXml.WriteTo(writer);

    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        decryptedToken = (SamlSecurityToken)FederatedAuthentication
            .FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration
            .SecurityTokenHandlers.ReadToken(reader);
}

var userEmail = decryptedToken.Assertion.Statements
    .OfType<SamlAttributeStatement>().Single()
    .Attributes[0].AttributeValues[0];
```

As a next step I'm going to read claims (e.g. user email) from the issued token.

I can extract a part of the related information by code above.

However, I'm looking for a more straightforward and secure way to extract full list of claims from an issued `SamlSecurityToken`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By far the easiest way to read these claims is to use the built-in [Validate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.securitytokenhandler.validatetoken(v=vs.110).aspx) method of the `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`.  This will convert you security token into a list (generally an 1-element list) of `ClaimsIdentity` objects, which in turn
have a `Claims` collection. Configuring such a handler from scratch can be a challenge.  Therefore you can just use the method you used for reading the token.  Call the `ValidateToken` on

```
FederatedAuthentication
    .FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration
    .SecurityTokenHandlers.ValidateToken()
```

to get the same result. The `Validate` method is a bit of a weird name for this convertion, which makes people search for it.